# How to get all pages data from site and save?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data currencies cost in page. I want to download all  data  from 2000.01.01 to 2018.12.01. In the page i can download or get data for one day but i want fol all period or for th one year and save it to csv file. How can i do this?

I have tried to get one date and save it to csv. And also try to parse it with urllib but also can`t get all data what i need.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_html('http://www.nbt.tj/ru/kurs/kurs.php?date=01.02.2016')
data = data[2]
data.to_csv('currencies.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create date range in custom format, loop, get DataFrame and write each DataFrame separately with append mode, where is necessary remove header and write only for first DataFrame:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2010-01-01', '2018-12-01').strftime('%d.%m.%Y')

for i, x in enumerate(dates):
    data = pd.read_html('http://www.nbt.tj/ru/kurs/kurs.php?date={}'.format(x))[2]
    if i == 0:
        data.to_csv('currencies.csv', index=False)
    else:
        data.to_csv('currencies.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=None)
```

Comment: Thanks but i have this problem : # this version of raise is a syntax error in Python 3

HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

Comment: @SoloMatador - i forget for `f` for f-strings., sorry.

Comment: @SoloMatador - completely changed solution with append to file, please check it.